# Common application property file for multiple microservice

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-config

I want to use a common application properties file for multiple microservices which will have some common configuration like DB Source config etc..I have use the config Server with Eureka server and zull Proxy.

**Issue:**

When using configServer we need to provide the spring.application.name = 'xyz'
which in turn find the xyz.properties for this microservice configuration.

The same way when we register the service with zuul proxy also need the same application name for configure the service path as zuul.routes.xyz.path = /iii/*.

Now I want that multiple service will share the same property file(xyz.properties) but need to register the zuul route as well so I have to provide the different name for each service. If I will provide the different name to each service they will not be able to locate the same property file.

I am new to spring boot micro services.

Comment: As part of spring cloud config, it is possible to provide multiple config names. ex. xyz.properties, common.properties. configure spring.config.client.name=xyz,common. Now you can use common as part of any service

Comment: @Barath.. I have commented the spring.application.name=xyz and add  spring.config.client.name=xyz,common... Now application is not getting up as it is not able to find the start-up properties(DB property)..

Comment: Possible to share your project?

Comment: I shared an example here [multiple-config-client](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/spring-cloud-multiple-config-client)

Comment: Thanks @Barath... Got it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**spring.config.client.name** supports multiple names separated by commas to load the configuration properties.

In this case, store the common properties in common.yml and xyz properties in xyz.yml. Finally, mention `spring.cloud.config.name: xyz,common`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      name: xyz,common
```

Output:

```
Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
Located environment: name=xyz,common, profiles=[default], label=null, version=91edcf96c6a88707bf39014a16ad5d301d6b4575, state=null
Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='configClient'}, MapPropertySource {name='https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/config-server-repository/common.yml'}, MapPropertySource {name='https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/config-server-repository/xyz.yml'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that the provided solution leverages the "spring.config.client.name" **client side** property semantics to achieve a **config server** behavior of serving properties files from multiple files other than *application[-profile]*.* and *{appname}[-profile]*.*

**However**, note that for a simple case and considering a root dir, the config server serves properties from files defined in this root dir or under a folder with the name of the application, that the property files under it correspond to, i.e. */{appname}/application[-profile].** or */{appname}/{appname}[-profile].**

The "*spring.config.client.name*" environment property instructs the config server which **application names** the requesting app matches with. This means that given a spring.config.client.name=**a**,**b** , the config server will assume serving properties **defined for app** (with name) **a and b** to the requesting app! This is not the exact same thing as I want my properties been served from **file *names* a and b**! Therefore we are **abusing** the property semantics for managing our config server serving from the file names we would like it to.

However, **due to the actual semantics of spring.config.client.name** the config server will serve everything applicable from

- /a[-profile].*
- /b[-profile].*
- /a/{applicable names}
- /b/{applicable names}

The **caveat** here is that we achieve what we want only for the root directory and, moreover, if we have a configserver that serves multiple springboot apps we loose the ability to have all our properties under our application's name-folder.

Even worse, **if there exists another app** (or -**attention!**- will exist in the future) **with the same name as one of our desired property file names**, the config server will start serving to our app ***ALL*** the configuration defined for **that other** app!!! This could end up in wrong and even harmful served configuration!

(I repeat it will serve ***everything*** applicable under /{**other-app-name-that-i-happened-to-use-as-filename-and-defined-it-through-spring.config.client.name**}/*!!!)

So beware when pirsuiting this approach!

I have issued a [pull request for spring-cloud-config-server 1.4.x](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/pull/1298), that supports defining additional file names, through a *spring.cloud.config.server.searchNames* environment property, in the same sense one can do for a single springboot app, as defined in the [Externalized Configuration.Application Property Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) section of the documentation, using the *spring.config.name* enviroment property. I hope they review it soon